# I tryed "mount -a" but in emergency mode but this what i faced

Tags: 22.04

root@user:~# **mount -a**
**Mount: /boot/efi: can not find UUID=2244-3705**
**mount: /mnt/usb-Flash_USB_DISK_3727052D55A8253822091-0:0 mount point dose not exist.**

Comment: Please edit your question to show the version of Ubuntu, the contents of /etc/fstab, and the output of `lsblk`

Answer (score 2):

`mount -a` will attempt to (re)mount all drives that are announced in the configuration file `/etc/fstab`. What you face, is that, in `/etc/fstab`, there is an attempt to mount a drive on a directory (`/mnt/usb-Flash_USB_DISK_3727052D55A8253822091-0:0`) that does not exist. Thus, check your system and clear up the inconsistencies between what you put in `/etc/fstab` and what is available on the system (drives and their mount points).